# Spring Cache: Evict multiple caches

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I'm using Spring Cache abstraction and I have multiple caches defined. Sometimes, when data changes, I want to evict more than one caches. 
Is there away to evict multiple cache using Spring's `@CacheEvict` annotation?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can do this:

```
@Caching(evict = {
    @CacheEvict("primary"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "secondary", key = "#p0")
})
```

Check out the [Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) for details

Comment: How to do if 1 is @CachePut & another one is @CacheEvict?

Comment: The Kotlin version of this is:
`@Caching(evict = [
    CacheEvict("primary"),
    CacheEvict(value = ["secondary"], key = "#p0")
])`

Answer (score 54):

Keep it compact: You can evict multiple caches by enumerating them inside the `@CacheEvict` annotation:

```
@CacheEvict(value = { "cache1", "cache2" }, allEntries = true)
```

Comment: Well yeah, assuming you want the same additional arguments (`allEntries = true`) to apply to all caches you specify.  In my experience that ain't often.

Comment: How would you deal with keys with this syntax?

Comment: Can mention keys like this `@CacheEvict(value = { "cache1", "cache2" }, key = "key")`